# Transform Freedom House Index into tidy format in R

Tags: r, excel

As title says, I want to transform the Freedom House Index from excel into tidy format in R. The FHI can be downloaded under https://freedomhouse.org/reports/publication-archives and then Country and Territory Ratings and Statuses, 1973-2021 and will look like this:
[FHI in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cJB8.png)

[image]

I have done it with the following code, but I think my solution is not very elegant and more like decompose and assamble. So I am looking for another solution, at best within the tidyverse. Thanks in advance.

```
#load packages
library(tidyverse)

#load data
library(readxl)
fh  <- read_excel("Data/Country_and_Territory_Ratings_and_Statuses_FIW1973-2021.xlsx", 
                  sheet = "Country Ratings, Statuses ", 
                  col_names = FALSE, na = "-")

# remove survey edition and years
fh_raw <- fh %>% 
  filter(...1 != c("Survey Edition", 
                   "Year(s) Under Review")) 
# save country names
cty <- unlist(fh_raw[1]) %>% 
  unname()

fh_raw <- fh_raw %>% 
  select(!...1)

# variable 
pr <- seq(to = length(fh_raw), by = 3)
cl <- seq(from = 2, to = length(fh_raw), by = 3)
status <- seq(from = 3, to = length(fh_raw), by = 3)

# select variables and transform into long-format
fh_pr <- fh_raw[pr] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:length(pr))
fh_pr <- unlist(fh_pr[2]) %>%
  unname() %>% as.numeric()


fh_cl <- fh_raw[cl] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:length(cl))
fh_cl <- unlist(fh_cl[2]) %>%
  unname() %>% as.numeric()


fh_status <- fh_raw[status] %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:length(status))
fh_status <- unlist(fh_status[2]) %>%
  unname() 

cty <- rep(cty, each = length(cl))

year = 1972:2020
year <- rep(year[year != 1981], times = 205) # 1981 is skipped

#create FH data frame
fh_long <- tibble(country = cty,
                  year = year,
                  pr = fh_pr,
                  cl = fh_cl,
                  status = fh_status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enter the magical world of `tidyxl` and `unpivotr` ;-)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyxl)
library(unpivotr)

file.to.read  <- "./Country_and_Territory_Ratings_and_Statuses_FIW1973-2021.xlsx"
sheet.to.read <- "Country Ratings, Statuses "

#read sheet's contents (take a look at it to see what you actrually just read in)
cells <- tidyxl::xlsx_cells( file.to.read, sheet = sheet.to.read)

ans <- cells %>%
  # Drop empty cells
  dplyr::filter(!is_blank) %>%
  # Setup headers from top and left side
  unpivotr::behead("up", "Survey_Edition") %>%
  unpivotr::behead("up", "year") %>%
  unpivotr::behead("up", "item") %>%
  unpivotr::behead("left", "country") %>%
  # There are unwanted training spaces in the item-clum, remove them
  dplyr::mutate(item = trimws(item)) %>%
  # Get value from numeric and character-column
  dplyr::mutate(value = ifelse(item == "Status", character, numeric)) %>%
  # Drop unneeded data
  dplyr::select(country, year, item, value) %>%
  # Fill down missing year info
  tidyr::fill(year, .direction = "down") %>%
  # Cast to wide format
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value)
```

**output**

```
# country     year               PR    CL    Status
# <chr>       <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr> 
# 1 Afghanistan 1972               4     5     PF    
# 2 Afghanistan 1973               7     6     NF    
# 3 Afghanistan 1974               7     6     NF    
# 4 Afghanistan 1975               7     6     NF    
# 5 Afghanistan 1976               7     6     NF    
# 6 Afghanistan 1977               6     6     NF    
# 7 Afghanistan 1978               7     7     NF    
# 8 Afghanistan 1979               7     7     NF    
# 9 Afghanistan 1980               7     7     NF    
#10 Afghanistan Jan.1981-Aug. 1982 7     7     NF    
#11 Afghanistan Aug.1982-Nov.1983  7     7     NF    
#12 Afghanistan Nov.1983-Nov.1984  7     7     NF    
#13 Afghanistan Nov.1984-Nov.1985  7     7     NF    
#14 Afghanistan Nov.1985-Nov.1986  7     7     NF    
#15 Afghanistan Nov.1986-Nov.1987  7     7     NF    
#16 Afghanistan Nov.1987-Nov.1988  6     6     NF    
#17 Afghanistan Nov.1988-Dec.1989  7     7     NF    
#18 Afghanistan 1990               7     7     NF    
#19 Afghanistan 1991               7     7     NF    
#20 Afghanistan 1992               6     6     NF  
# ...
```

Comment: Can you explain how to choose the direction in the `behead()` statements? I have read the unpivotr documentation but am not clear on which data cells and header cells we should be considering at each step.